# Mysqli: Set different autoincrement ID based on $value

Tags: php, mysql

I try to set different autoincrement ID based on $year in the same table on INSERT TO.
An example:

Clients that order services for the 2015 must have autoincrement ID 1500XXXX
Clients that order services for the 2016 must have autoincrement ID 1600XXXX

Its possible? And if yes, how can i do it?

Comment: not possible. you'd have to reset to the table's auto_increment value BEFORE you do the insert that would use the specific range of values, and that means you'll invariably end up with colllisions/invalid increments. why not make a composite key? (year,id)? then you simply have a mysql scheduled job reset the auto increment to 1 at midnight on jan 1st.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your quick answer, can you suggest me how generate a key (year,id) on INSERT TO?

Comment: It's not really a good design practice to include such information in the primary key. What happens, if I order a service for this year, then change my mind and push the order to next year? I would rather display the year part from the delivery date in fron of your autoincrement id and achieve the same look, but would not need to change the underlying data.

Comment: But i need that if clients tomorrow order a service for the 2016 have an ID that begin by 1 or by 1600XXX (sorry for my MACCHERONI english :-)